# At what point of time branches start appearing?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe

At the end of the TV show "Loki", Kang died and we see new timelines started to branch off the sacred time line.

As Kang is at the end of time, I wonder the effect of his death on the sacred timeline started at what point? I can't find a reason to think the branches will start appearing after the events of "WandaVision".

Comment: The Sacred Timeline stretches from the beginning of time to the end of time so branches can appear ANYWHERE along it....and do. The purpose of the TVA was to prune those branches by travelling through time to stop them splitting off.

Comment: The suggested question/answer doesn't really answer my question, maybe addresses a related issue.

Comment: @Mocas I have voted to reopen this question - I believe you can vote to reopen it too. If it does not get reopened after a day or two, please raise this issue at [meta].